# Why we need maven if there's javac that compiles the code?

Tags: java, maven

I'm totally new to java programming but I'm been programming with .Net and PHP. In .Net all you have to do is run it and it will output exe file in the bin dir which is already deployable, right? I'm confused with the use of maven and javac. I've been searching around but I don't still able to fathom them.

What I'm thinking is that when a certain source code is to be compiled in java, you use the cmd "javac " which is similar to "Run" in .Net. So why do we need Maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Maven is a** software project management and comprehension tool **and not** a programming language compiler like **javac**.

Maven gives you a way to manage your project dependencies through out the development and deployment phases of it, meaning that it ensures that you have the necessary libraries to develop, build and deploy your project. Javac only gives a way to compile your Java code.

Comment: Am I correct of my understanding that maven is something like Setup and Deployment in .Net platform? Also, what's the output of a maven project? The jar file also confuses me

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Setup and Deployment in .Net platform but, from what I briefly read it is similiar to Maven. The output of a Maven project depends on its configuration, it can be a .jar or a .war file. Without going into much detail, Maven builds the project for you (it uses javac to compile your stuff) and then it packages it into something like a .jar (it does more than that, but in a general way this is it). About the jar file, there are two types of jars, the runnable ones and the library ones. (will continue in the next comment)

Comment: The runnable jars are similar to the executable files in Windows (.exe) and the library jars are libraries that can be included in projects, etc.

Comment: OK it's more clear to me now... thank you expert for your help.

One more thing please, about the gar file. What is it?

(Now I realized, it's hard migrating from .Net to Java.)

Comment: I you mean the .jar file? It is kinda a .zip file that stores your compiled code.

Comment: No. I kinda know already about the jar file, thanks for your insights you shared to me, I really appreciate it, but now it's gar file. I'm not sure if it's really part or something useful in java world but in the office they want me to output from Jenkins jobs into a gar file. Sorry, I'm new to Java world.

Answer (score 1):

Building an application is a lot harder than running javac. There are two big motivations for build tools like Maven: cross-platform builds and dependency tracking.

Part of life for Java developers is needing to build applications on multiple platforms. A build has to run locally on a developer's machine, it also has to run on a Continuous Integration server or on some other environment. (And for some projects developers may have different platforms so even just getting a build to run on everyone's machine may require cross-platform builds.) Getting shell scripts to run in multiple environments proved to be prohibitively painful, and people started creating things like Ant and later Maven.

Any sizeable Java application is put together using dozens of third party libraries and frameworks. Most of these third party components have dependencies on other libraries, keeping track of the tangled mess is too much work for anybody. An important function of Maven is to pull in dependencies, making sure the libraries have compatible versions.